# How do I draw a rectangle in Android?

Tags: android, drawrect

I'm trying to make a custom banner with my logo on it. [This is what I want it to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKHis.png) I have already tried multiple methods, yet they didn't seem to work. The following is what I tried.

This is the CustomView class:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;

/**
 * Created by Michael on 12/24/2017.
 */

public class CustomView extends View {
private Rect rectangle;
private Paint paint;

public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    int x = 50;
    int y = 50;
    int sideLength = 200;

    // create a rectangle that we'll draw later
    rectangle = new Rect(x, y, sideLength, sideLength);

    // create the Paint and set its color
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle, paint);
  }
}
```

This is the MainActivity Class:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new CustomView(this));

  }
}
```

Edit: My current approach does nothing. The current code has no effect on the app's layout.

Comment: please [edit] your question to include what is wrong with your current approach

Comment: Your code draws a rectangle, but what does this have to do with the image you posted?

Comment: The problem is it's not drawing a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >

            <solid android:color="@color/myColor" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/myLogo" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

You could try something like this. Set this drawable as background of framelayout.